# Using regexp_replace to replace single quotes around string but not within words e.g. can't

Tags: bash, text-processing, replace, postgresql

I'm using the below code from a bash script to replace single quotes from my title column in a postgres database with spaces.

```
psql -U postgres -d my_database -c "UPDATE my_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '''', ' ', 'g')"
```

My problem is that I intended to remove the single quotes around strings, for example, like this:

```
this is example 'number one' ok
```

becomes

```
this is example  number one  ok
```

This works as I had hoped.However, it is also removing the single quotes from within words, so:

```
can't
```

becomes

```
can t
```

How can I specify that I only want to replace the single quotes around strings.

Comment: so quotes should be removed from `this is 'the one' ` but not from `you can't and you won't ` ? I am not sure regexp will help you there ...

Comment: it is possible to some extent: you must be sure that in your data any quoted sequence has a non-letter char in front of it and non-letter char behind it. Otherwise you need to use some dictionary or algorithm to detect the cases like `won't`, `can't`, `it's`, e.t.c. and reject replacements, i.e. it can't be implemented as a pure regular expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428986/regex-to-find-complete-words-at-postgresql#17429058

Comment: @thrig Beware that testing for word boundaries doesn't help, since from the point of view of a regexp engine, the quote in `can't` is followed and preceded by a word boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any nice way to do it with just one replacement. But if four replacements are fine, proceed as follows:

1. Replace `\A'` by  (that is, replace `'` at the beginning of the string).
2. Replace `'\Z` by  (that is, replace `'` at the end of the string).
3. Globally replace `([^[:alnum:]])'` by `\1`  (that is, replace every sequence of a non-alphanumeric character and `'` by the non-alphanumeric character and ).
4. Globally replace `'([^[:alnum:]])` by  `\1` (that is, replace every sequence of `'` and a non-alphanumeric character by  and the non-alphanumeric character.)

The net effect is to replace every `'`, except those that are preceded *and* followed by an alphanumeric character.

Disclaimer: I have no clue about PostgreSQL; you have to translate it into PostgreSQL syntax yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cleverer regex: If you replace " `'`" and "`'` " (<kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>APOSTROPHE</kbd> and <kbd>APOSTROPHE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd>) you will miss the intra-word apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid apostrohpes in words, look for apostrophes, which do not have a letter left or right. A possible regular expression to look for such apostrophes could be

```
([A-Za-z])\'([^A-Za-z])|([^A-Za-z])\'([A-Za-z])|([^A-Za-z])\'([^A-Za-z])
```

or shorter

```
\'([^A-Za-z])|([^A-Za-z])\'
```

or even shorter

```
\'([^\w])|([^\w])\'
```

I guess regexp_replace would be

```
regexp_replace(title, '\'([^\w])|([^\w])\'', '\1', 'g')
```

I am not familiar with psql, so the right synatx might be

```
regexp_replace(title, '''([^\w])|([^\w])''', '\1', 'g')
```